# How do I keep the value of a checkbox in an invalid form in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel 8 **blogging application**. The "Add article" form has a "switch" (checkbox) that lets the user choose whether or not the post will be a **featured** one.

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('dashboard.articles.add') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        @csrf

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('title') has-error @enderror">
            <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" autocomplete="title" autofocus>

            @error('title')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @enderror
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="short_description" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Short description') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('short_description') has-error @enderror">
                <input id="short_description" type="text" placeholder="Short description" class="form-control @error('short_description') is-invalid @enderror" name="short_description" value="{{ old('short_description') }}" autocomplete="short_description" autofocus>

                @error('short_description')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="category" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Category') }}</label>
        
            <div class="col-md-12 @error('category_id') has-error @enderror">
        
                <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                    <option value="0">Pick a category</option>
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
        
                    @error('category_id')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center switch-toggle">
                <p class="mb-0 me-3">Featured article?</p>
                <input id="featured" class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured">
                <label class="px-1" for="featured">{{ __('Toggle') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">{{ __('Save') }}</button>

</form>
```

The controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    
    private $rules = [
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:article_categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'short_description' => 'required|string|max:190',
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Please pick a category for the article',
        'title.required' => 'Please provide a title for the article',
        'short_description.required' => 'The article needs a short description',
        'short_description.max' => 'The short description field is too long',
    ];
    
    public function categories() {
        return ArticleCategory::all();
    }
    

    public function create() {
        // Load the view and populate the form with categories
        return view('dashboard/add-article',
            ['categories' => $this->categories()]
        );
    }

    public function save(Request $request) {
        // Validate form (with custom messages)
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        $fields = $validator->validated();

        // Turn the 'featured' field value into a tiny integer
        $fields['featured'] = $request->get('featured') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;


        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'featured' => $fields['featured'],
        ];

        // Insert data in the 'articles' table
        $query = Article::create($form_data);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('success', 'The article titled "' . $form_data['title'] . '" was added');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Adding article failed');
        }
    }
}
```

#### The problem

When an attempt is made to submit the *invalid form*, the fields that are *valid* keep their values.

The unintended exception to the rule is the checkbox `<input id="featured" class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured">`

###### What is my mistake?

Comment: You're never checking for or handling `old('featured')`, so of course your checkbox and `<select>` elements do not keep their selected values when invalid. Remember that `<option>` elements have a `selected` property, and `<input type="checkbox">` elements have a `checked` property; that should be set based on `old()` input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your input has no value, so you can only check on existence not on value in controller (`$request->get('featured')` will never have the value `on`)
2. You need to use `old('featured')` on that field too
3. You can skip the check on the featured field in the controller if you set the values to 0 and 1 in the form

```
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center switch-toggle">
                <p class="mb-0 me-3">Featured article?</p>
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="featured">
                <input {{ old('featured') ? 'checked':'' }} id="featured" value="1" class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured">
                <label class="px-1" for="featured">{{ __('Toggle') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The hidden field is to send the value `0` if the checkbox is not checked. A checkbox input is not sent in the request if it is not checked.

When checked, the input value will be overwritten to `1`.

In the controller you can directly use the input

```
        $fields = $validator->validated();

        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'featured' => $fields['featured'],
        ];
```